# Как правильно обрабатывать время при помощи Java и SQL?

Tags: java

Каким типом данных можно хранить дату и время формата `YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS` и просто время `HH:MM:SS` в базе данных. Я нашел только два решения - один в виде строк, но он к сожалению имеет свои недостатки - отсутствие возможности сортировки информации SQL-запросом. И второй - в виде java.SQL.Date, но при его помощи я получаю только YY-mm-DD в базе данных(возможно я не правильно его применяю). Какие ещё есть способы помимо тех, про которые я упомянул? И каким лучше пользоваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

лучше всего хранить дату в `long` используя `new Date().getTime()` или `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`
потом все можно трансформировать в любой формат с помощью `SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от базы данных и конкретной задачи. База может располагать нативными типами данных для дат,  времени, дат и времени, с учетом часовых поясов и без него, для простого UNIX epoch timestamp (который как long из соседнего ответа). Обычно вы захотите хранить время по UTC или Unix epoch time.

Хранить как строку - обычно не лучшее решение, но вынужденное, если речь идет о какой-нибудь строковой key-value базе. Если же вам приходится это делать, следуйте стандарту [ISO 8601](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) и приводите время к UTC.

---

Внутри Java **никогда** не пишите велосипедов для работы с датами и временем. Избегайте класса `Calendar`.

В Java 7 и ранее (если почему-то вы вынуждены писать на ней) используйте [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

В Java 8+ используйте новые [Java Time API (`java.time`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), (которые основаны на Joda-Time) или воспользуйтесь опять же Joda-Time.

В строковое представление с нужным часовым поясом переводите дату, когда нужно показать ее пользователю.

---

Почему надо быть аккуратным при работе со временем хорошо описали на Хабре:

- [Что должен знать о времени каждый программист](https://habrahabr.ru/post/123461/)
- [Правильная работа с датой и временем](https://habrahabr.ru/post/278527/)